# scala-spark: back to back clicks

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning scala and spark so pretty new to both technologies:

Assume I have a file like this:

```
"1421453179.157"        P0105451998  "SCREEN"   
"1421453179.157"        P0106586529  "PRESENTATION"     
"1421453179.157"        P0108481590   NULL    
"1421453179.157"        P0108481590  "SCREEN"        
"1421453179.157"        P0112397365  "FULL_SCREEN"   
"1421453179.157"        P0113994553  "FULL_SCREEN"   
"1421453179.158"        P0112360870  "DATA_INFO"    dataId:5913974361807341112
"1421453179.159"        P0112360870  "DATA_INFO"    dataId:7658923479992321112   
"1421453179.160"        P0108137271  "SCREEN"   
"1421453179.161"        P0103681986  "SCREEN"   
"1421453179.162"        P0104229251  "PRESENTATION"
```

first column is time, second column is user_id, third column has a meaning depend on the data that is in the 4th column.

I want to accomplish following:

I want to find consecutive DATA_INFO records and generate following

```
P0112360870, 5913974361807341112|7658923479992321112
```

The verbal interpretation of that row would be user `P0112360870` click `5913974361807341112|7658923479992321112` first click should be at the beginning here 5913974361807341112 is the first click.

I start with following:

```
val data=sc.textFile("hdfs://*").map(line=> {val tks=line.split("\t",3); (tks(1),(tks(0),tks(2))) } )
val data2=data.groupBy( a=> a._1).take(1000)
```

But can't figure out to go forward from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your way of going about this starts off wrong. If you know your keys, then set it up as a proper key-value tuple with the following:

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://*")
  .map(_.split("\t",3)) //Split on tabs
  .map(tks=>(tks(1),(tks(0),tks(2)))) //Create a (key, Tuple2) pairing
  .reduceByKey(
    (x,y)=>
    if(x._1 contains "DATA_INFO") (s"${x._2}|${y._2}".replace("dataId:",""), "")
    else x //Ignore duplicate non-DATA_INFO elements by dropping?????
  )
```

The biggest thing to note is that you need to handle the else case however is appropriate.

CLARIFICATION PER REQUEST

```
(s"${x._2}|${y._2}".replace("dataId:",""), "") //Using string interpolation
```

is the same as

```
val concatenatedString = x._2 +"|"+y._2
val concatStringWithoutMetaData = concatenatedString.replace("dataId:","")
(concatStringWithoutMetaData, "") //Return the new string with an empty final column
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Could you please explain whats going on at `(s"${x._2}|${y._2}".replace("entityId:",""), "")` its bit cryptic to me.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis I added more detail after the original answer. Does this clarify it for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
val data=sc.textFile("hdfs://*").map( line => line.split( "\t" ).toList )

// you probably want only those with pxx with at least some data.
val filteredData = data.filter( l => l.length > 3 )

val groupedData = data.groupBy( l => l( 1 ) )

val iWantedThis = groupedData.map( ( pxxx, iterOfList ) => {
    // every pxxxx group will have at least one entry with data.
    val firstData = iterOfList.head( 3 )
    // Now concatenate all other data's to the firstdata
    val datas = iterOfList.tail.foldLeft( firstData )( ( fd, l ) => fd + "|" + l( 3 ) )
    // return the string with \t as separtor.
    List( pxxx, datas ).mkString( "\t" )
} )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite often useful to use `spark-shell` (which is like a REPL for Spark) just to test your ideas. Especially when you're new to it.

Run spark shell (in `bin/spark-shell`), and create your test data set:

```
val input = """
"1421453179.157"        P0105451998  "SCREEN"   
"1421453179.157"        P0106586529  "PRESENTATION"     
"1421453179.157"        P0108481590   NULL    
"1421453179.157"        P0108481590  "SCREEN"        
"1421453179.157"        P0112397365  "FULL_SCREEN"   
"1421453179.157"        P0113994553  "FULL_SCREEN"   
"1421453179.158"        P0112360870  "DATA_INFO"    dataId:5913974361807341112
"1421453179.159"        P0112360870  "DATA_INFO"    dataId:7658923479992321112   
"1421453179.160"        P0108137271  "SCREEN"   
"1421453179.161"        P0103681986  "SCREEN"   
"1421453179.162"        P0104229251  "PRESENTATION""""


sc.parallelize(input.split("\n").map(_.trim)).map(_.split("\\s+")).
  filter(_.length > 3). // take only > 3 (so containing dataId)
  map(a => a(1) -> a(3).split(":")(1) ). // create a pair for each row your user -> click
  reduceByKey(_ + "|" + _). // reduce clicks per user
  collect // get it to the driver
```

When you run it you should see more or less this:

```
res0: Array[(String, String)] = Array((P0112360870,5913974361807341112|7658923479992321112))
```

Which I think is what you're looking for.